# Kafka connect tasks die with NPE randomly

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I started running a custom kafka connect plugin that dumps data from kafka into ElasticSearch, and periodically my tasks just die for no reason (after a few hours to a day)

I see this in the connect status:

```
curl -s http://localhost:8083/connectors/my-custom-sink/status | python -m json.tool
{
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "MASKED_IP1:8083"
    },
    "name": "my-custom-sink",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig.<init>(TaskConfig.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:313)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:834)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1500(DistributedHerder.java:101)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:848)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:844)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n",
            "worker_id": "MASKED_IP1:8083"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig.<init>(TaskConfig.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:313)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:834)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1500(DistributedHerder.java:101)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:848)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:844)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n",
            "worker_id": "MASKED_IP2:8083"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "MASKED_IP3:8083"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated (i.e. what is kafka trying to do when it threw a npe)

UPDATE:
This is kafka 0.10.2.0

And here's what I see in the worker's log just before it died

```
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,146  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.2.0
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,146  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : 576d93a8dc0cf421
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,172  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: Discovered coordinator MASKED_FQDN:9092 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) for group my-group.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,223  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Removed connector my-group due to null configuration. This is usually intentional and does not indicate an issue.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,223  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Removed connector my-group due to null configuration. This is usually intentional and does not indicate an issue.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,223  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Removed connector my-group due to null configuration. This is usually intentional and does not indicate an issue.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,224  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Removed connector my-group due to null configuration. This is usually intentional and does not indicate an issue.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,224  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Removed connector my-group due to null configuration. This is usually intentional and does not indicate an issue.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,226  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Removed connector my-group due to null configuration. This is usually intentional and does not indicate an issue.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,228  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog: Finished reading KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-configs
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,228  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog: Started KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-configs
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,228  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore: Started KafkaConfigBackingStore
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,233  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Herder started
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,239  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: Discovered coordinator MASKED_FQDN1:9092 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) for group my-group.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:17,241  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: (Re-)joining group my-group
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:20,868  [CLASSPATH traversal thread.] org.reflections.Reflections: Reflections took 3600 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 7612 keys and 36389 values 
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,511  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: Successfully joined group my-group with generation 804011
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,516  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-29930623-f17a-43ca-bed9-7f8a6fb5317a', leaderUrl='http://MASKED_IP:8083/', offset=2, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[my-group]}
WARN  2017-07-30 07:38:22,521  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Catching up to assignment's config offset.
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,521  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 2, reading to end of config log
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,846  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: 2
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,846  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 2
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,849  [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Starting task my-group
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,849  [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker: Creating task my-group
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,851  [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig: ConnectorConfig values: 
        connector.class = IndexerSinkConnector
        key.converter = null
        name = my-group
        tasks.max = 3
        transforms = null
        value.converter = null

ERROR 2017-07-30 07:38:22,856  [pool-6-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker: Failed to start task my-group
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:52)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig.<init>(TaskConfig.java:52)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:313)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:834)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1500(DistributedHerder.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:848)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:844)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO  2017-07-30 07:38:22,890  [DistributedHerder] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder: Finished starting connectors and tasks
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to start a task. What version is this? What do you see in the worker logs just before the npe?

Comment: @dawsaw I updated version and added logs in question.

Comment: Ah your converter are null. Set something for key.converter and value.converter and see if that helps? Obviously that should be handled better than an npe but if it fixes your immediate problem that'd be good to know.

Comment: I'm not sure why it says null, because I'm passing in value for the key/value converters. In fact, even when it is running, it still says null (but I can see the key/value converters being used)

Comment: Out of interest, what's the driver for writing your own instead of using https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch?

Comment: The existing one does not allow data splitting. i.e. each one of our kafka record contains multiple es document, and we need to split it in a custom manner. Also, we need to implement throttling, etc

Comment: I think the npe is originating from here where it's trying to start the task but the worker object is null https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.2.0/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/distributed/DistributedHerder.java#L834

Comment: Scratch that it's here https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.2.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/AbstractConfig.java#L52 do you have multiple partitions in your config topic?

Comment: I see, I do have multiple partitions in my config topic. I'll try setting it to just 1 and see if this helps. I'll report back in a few days. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @dawsaw It did fix the problem, thanks! If you would post this as a solution, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NPE originates here https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.2.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/AbstractConfig.java#L52 do you have multiple partitions in your config topic? Only one partition is allowed for the config topic. This requirement is strictly enforced starting in 0.11 so future versions shouldn't hit this issue.

Comment: I am still seeing the same error, and the no. of partitions is 1 only for me.